# Find driver used for backlight control

Tags: kernel, drivers, backlight

I can control backlight using `/sys/class/backlight/..` but is there a way to identify which driver (module) is used internally to actually control the backlight intensity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ ls -ld /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Jun  3 10:08 /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight

$ ls -l /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/driver
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Jun  3 09:08 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/driver
 -> ../../../bus/pci/drivers/i915

$ ls -l /sys/bus/pci/drivers/i915/module
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Jun  4 17:04 /sys/bus/pci/drivers/i915/module 
 -> ../../../../module/i915
```

don't ask me exactly how I guess the level that holds `driver` :). I think you might be supposed to check each level, starting with the longest path and working down, but that's a bit tedious.

Comment: This gets it wrong in some cases at least; *e.g.* I have one system which has a GPU controlled by `i915` but whose backlight is controlled by `ddcci_backlight`...

Comment: @StephenKitt surely the "tedious" method will find the specific driver for the backlight?  The backlight device won't always be a child device of the GPU. E.g. on an eeepc, backlight may be controlled by an eeepc-specific driver. the backlight device is a child of a "platform device", and you can find the eeepc driver (and then the module) by looking at that platform device.

Comment: Ah you’re right, the “tedious” method finds it (`/sys/class/backlight/ddcci6` links to `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1/i2c-6/6-0037/ddcci6/backlight/ddcci6`, `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1/i2c-6/6-0037/ddcci6/driver` links to `/sys/bus/ddcci/drivers/ddcci-backlight`).